# print first 8 columns and one of the last three non-zero columns linux/awk/sed/R

Tags: r, linux, awk, sed

I want to print first 8 columns and one of the columns from last 3 columns which has non-zero value from the file. Sample input:

```
chr2    219541089   C   15  0   12  0   3   0   0   20
chr20   31831068    C   48  3   45  0   0   6.25    0   0
chr20   38724789    C   41  4   37  0   0   9.7561  0   0
chr20   63080141    C   95  0   91  4   0   0   4.21053 0
chr22   37642528    C   31  2   29  0   0   6.45161 0   0
```

desired output:

```
chr2    219541089   C   15  0   12  0   3   20
chr20   31831068    C   48  3   45  0   0   6.25
chr20   38724789    C   41  4   37  0   0   9.7561
chr20   63080141    C   95  0   91  4   0   4.21053
chr22   37642528    C   31  2   29  0   0   6.45161
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More elementary solution could be

```
cbind(df[,1:8], pmax(df[,9], df[,10], df[,11]))
```

where df is your data frame.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a quick and simple response Martin!

Comment: It should be stated that, however, it will not work if it is possible that all three rightmost rows can be negative simultaneously.

Comment: Sure Martin, I got that. Thanks! Also, could there be modification to print the respective column name also as separate column?

Answer (score 0):

We can `coalesce` after replacing the 0s to NA .  Replace the 0's to NA with `replace` after selecting the columns of interest (9:11) in `mutate_at`, then create a new column with `mutate` by removing the NA in each row and select first non-NA element from columns 9 to 11 (`coalesce`) and remove the unwanted columns with `select`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate_at(9:11, funs(replace(., .==0, NA_real_))) %>%
    mutate(colN = coalesce(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)[9:11]))) %>%
    select(-(9:11))
#    v1        v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8     colN
#1  chr2 219541089  C 15  0 12  0  3 20.00000
#2 chr20  31831068  C 48  3 45  0  0  6.25000
#3 chr20  38724789  C 41  4 37  0  0  9.75610
#4 chr20  63080141  C 95  0 91  4  0  4.21053
#5 chr22  37642528  C 31  2 29  0  0  6.45161
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("chr2", "chr20", "chr20", "chr20", "chr22"
), v2 = c(219541089L, 31831068L, 38724789L, 63080141L, 37642528L
), v3 = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), v4 = c(15L, 48L, 41L, 95L, 
31L), v5 = c(0L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 2L), v6 = c(12L, 45L, 37L, 91L, 
29L), v7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L), v8 = c(3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
v9 = c(0, 6.25, 9.7561, 0, 6.45161), v10 = c(0, 0, 0, 4.21053, 
0), v11 = c(20L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun for such quick answer! could you please explain it a little as I am a newbie in R!

Comment: @aan Sure, I updated the solution with some description

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!

Answer (score 0):

With awk

```
awk '{$(NF-2) = $(NF-2) ? $(NF-2) : ($(NF-1) ? $(NF-1) : $NF); $(NF-1) = $NF = ""}1' file
```

or perl (assumes exactly 1 of the last 3 values will be non-zero)

```
perl -lane '@first = splice @F,0,8; print "@{[ @first, grep {$_} @F ]}"' file
```

pipe the output into `| column -t` to make it prettier.

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'function zv(x,y) {return x?x:y} 
                   {v=zv($(NF-2),zv($(NF-1),$NF)); NF-=2; $NF=v}1' file

chr2    219541089       C       15      0       12      0       3       20
chr20   31831068        C       48      3       45      0       0       6.25
chr20   38724789        C       41      4       37      0       0       9.7561
chr20   63080141        C       95      0       91      4       0       4.21053
chr22   37642528        C       31      2       29      0       0       6.45161
```

takes the first non-zero value, in case there are more than one.